# The script I'm using to redirect my homepage isn't working the way I need it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, tumblr

I'm using the code below to redirect my Tumblr homepage to my latest post.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.getJSON('http://mydomain.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?', function(result) {
      window.location.href = result.posts[0].url;
   });
});
</script>
```

I'm having two problems with it. First, it doesn't redirect instantly, it loads my homepage and then changes the URL, even though I've placed it above my `<head>` tag. Then when it does redirect it starts refreshing every few seconds. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `getJSON` is asynchronous, so I think it doesn't matter where you put your call, it's going to fire off a request that is separate from the page being rendered. At the point that the response is received, then it will be redirected. Your "delay" is the fact that the request does take time.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it waits is because any code you place in `$(document).ready` waits for the for the document to load first before it is executed.

For the refreshing part, I guess you have this same code in your page with the lastest post.

Comment: I removed `$(document).ready` but there's still a short delay. And you're right about the refreshing part, just not sure how to change it haha

Comment: @coyotee the delay is because of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

It redirects after you load the page because code in `$(document).ready(function(){ ...});`  is executed after page load.
To avoid refresh after redirect, try something like:

```
if(window.location.href !== result.posts[0].url) {
   window.location.href = result.posts[0].url;
}
```

Comment: I tried using this but it's still refreshing. It's driving me nuts haha!